# mysql select from table where two (or more) rows match,

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say we have shirts in our database. All shirts have size and color (and many other options, but for now I'm trying to figure it out with two).

The table is something like:

```
+-------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
| variation_attributes_id | variation_id | attribute_id | option_id |
+-------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
|                       1 |            1 | size         | s         |
|                       2 |            1 | color        | red       |
|                       3 |            2 | size         | m         |
|                       4 |            2 | color        | red       |
|                       5 |            3 | size         | s         |
|                       6 |            3 | color        | green     |
|                       7 |            4 | size         | m         |
|                       8 |            4 | color        | green     |
+-------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
```

How to select unique `variation_id`. For example where `size` is `S` and `color` is `Green` should return `variation_id` == 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that with a simple `JOIN` (self-join, meaning you join the table with itself under specific conditions). Assuming your table is named `shirts`, it goes like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s1.variation_id 
FROM shirts s1
JOIN shirts s2 ON s1.variation_id = s2.variation_id
WHERE (s1.attribute_id = 'size' AND s1.option_id='s')
  AND (s2.attribute_id = 'color' AND s2.option_id='green')
```

It will return all variation_id that have the color and size that you need, filtering out all other variation_id's.

This query will work fine and it's performance will be OK if you have and index like `(variation_id, attribute_id, option_id)`

What is more, this query lets you get `variation_ids` **with more complicated arguments**, which is much harder using `HAVING COUNT(*) = ?`.

For example - you need to find all `variation_ids` that have a size 's' or 'm', and color of 'green' or 'yellow'

```
SELECT DISTINCT s1.variation_id 
FROM shirts s1
JOIN shirts s2 ON s1.variation_id = s2.variation_id
WHERE (s1.attribute_id = 'size' AND s1.option_id IN ('s', 'm'))
  AND (s2.attribute_id = 'color' AND s2.option_id IN ('green', 'yellow'))
```

Comment: This solution is what I was looking for. Selecting multiple options was also part of the issue, so at this point this is the best answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply necessary conditions in the `where` clause and `count` their occurrences in the `having` clause:

```
select variation_id
from tbl
where ( attribute_id = 'size' and option_id = 's' )
   or ( attribute_id = 'color' and option_id = 'green' )
group by variation_id
having count(*) = 2
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34390d/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` and subquery:

```
SELECT variation_id
FROM your_table t1
WHERE attribute_id = 'color'
  AND option_id  = 'green'
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM your_table t2
              WHERE t1.variation_id = t2.variation_id
                AND t2.attribute_id = 'size'
                AND t2.option_id = 's');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.`variation_id`
FROM(
(SELECT *
 FROM table_name
WHERE `attribute_id` = 'size') T1 
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT *
     FROM table_name
    WHERE `option_id ` = 's') T2 ON T1.`variation_id` = T2.`variation_id`)
```

Hope this helps.